# Can scipy.optimize minimize functions of complex variables at all and how?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to minimize a function of a complex (vector) variable using `scipy.optimize`. My results so far indicate that it may not be possible. To investigate the problem, I have implemented a simple example - minimize the 2-norm of a complex vector with an offset:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def fun(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x - 1j * np.ones(2), 2)

sol = fmin(fun, x0=np.ones(2) + 0j)
```

The output is

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 2.000000
         Iterations: 38
         Function evaluations: 69

>>> sol
array([-2.10235293e-05,  2.54845649e-05])
```

Clearly, the solution should be

```
array([0.+1.j, 0.+1.j])
```

Disappointed with this outcome, I have also tried `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def fun(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x - 1j * np.ones(2), 1)

sol = minimize(fun, x0=np.ones(2) + 0j)
```

The output is

```
>>> sol
      fun: 2.0
 hess_inv: array([[ 9.99997339e-01, -2.66135332e-06],
       [-2.66135332e-06,  9.99997339e-01]])
      jac: array([0., 0.])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 24
      nit: 5
     njev: 6
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([6.18479071e-09+0.j, 6.18479071e-09+0.j])
```

Not good either. I have tried specifying all of the possible methods for `minimize` (supplying the Jacobian and Hessian as necessary), but none of them reach the correct result. Most of them cause `ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part`, indicating that they cannot handle complex numbers correctly.

Is this possible at all using `scipy.optimize`?

If so, I would very much appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

If not, do you perhaps have suggestions for alternative optimization tools (for Python) that allow this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The minimization methods of SciPy work with real arguments only. But minimization on the complex space C<sup>n</sup> amounts to minimization on R<sup>2n</sup>, the algebra of complex numbers never enters the consideration. Thus, adding two wrappers for conversion from C<sup>n</sup> to R<sup>2n</sup> and back, you can optimize over complex numbers.

```
def real_to_complex(z):      # real vector of length 2n -> complex of length n
    return z[:len(z)//2] + 1j * z[len(z)//2:]

def complex_to_real(z):      # complex vector of length n -> real of length 2n
    return np.concatenate((np.real(z), np.imag(z)))

sol = minimize(lambda z: fun(real_to_complex(z)), x0=complex_to_real(np.ones(2) + 0j))
print(real_to_complex(sol.x))   # [-7.40376620e-09+1.j -8.77719406e-09+1.j]
```

You mention Jacobian and Hessian... but minimization only makes sense for real-valued functions, and those are never differentiable with respect to complex variables. The Jacobian and Hessian would have to be computed over R<sup>2n</sup> anyway, treating the real and imaginary parts as separate variables.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand: are you saying that I cannot minimize $\|x - c\|_2$ if $x$ and/or $c$ are complex? The norm of a complex vector seems to make sense to me and as such the minimizer of this small example is $x = c$.

Comment: I'm not saying that. I'm saying the function being minimized is f(x) = ||x-c||, which is real-valued, hence not differentiable in the complex sense.

Comment: You might want to look for the Wirtingel derivative. In https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/631019/631019.pdf, the author explained,
"Due to the property that the non-trivial real-valued functions are not analytic, stationary points of the real-valued f(z) cannot be obtained by searching for points z where the derivative f'(z) is zero. However, we can detect stationary points z of f(z) by a vanishing differential df."
As for the optimization algorithm in complex variables, you can read this article: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/110832124?mobileUi=0

Answer (score 1):

I have needed to minimize the departure of a complex valued model function upon complex valued parameters, over a real domain.

A toy example:

```
def f(x, a, b):
    ab = complex(a,b);
    return np.exp(x*ab)
```

And suppose that I have data `DATA` `for x = np.arange(N)`. Note that `x` is *real*.

What I did was this:

```
def helper(x, a, b):
    return abs(f(x,a,b) - DATA[x])
```

and then I can use `curve_fit()`:

```
curve_fit(helper, np.arange(N), np.zeros(N), p0 = [1,0])
```

What is happening is this:  By subtracting the data from the model function, the new "ideal" output is all zeroes, which can be (must be) real in order for `curve_fit()` to work. The complex parameter `ab = a + jb` has been broken into its real and imaginary parts.  The `helper()` function returns the absolute value of the difference between the model and the data.

A critical issue is that `curve_fit()` doesn't evaluate any other x values than those you give it. Otherwise `DATA[x]` would fail.

Note that by using `abs()` I'm achieving an L1 fit (more or less).  One could just as well use `abs()**2` to get an L2 fit ... but why one would use L1 or L2 is a topic for another day.

You could fret, "suppose that the `x[]` aren't integers (but are real)?" which my code requires.  Well, that's doable, simply by putting them into an array, and indexing that.  There's probably some clever hack using a dictionary that would address this issue, too.

<s>Sorry about the code formatting; haven't figured out the markup yet.</s>