# Finding the x that makes the function minimum python

Tags: python, scipy, minimum, scipy-optimize

[image]I have a function and I am trying to find the minimum.
here is my code:

```py
import nyumpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import basinhopping, Bounds
from scipy import optimize
x=np.arange(-180.0,180.0)
bounds = Bounds(-180., 180.)
def P1_adj(x):
    return 60450.64625041*np.exp(1j*(57.29*1.75056445+x))

print(optimize.minimize(P1_adj, x0=0))
```

When I run it, I get this error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'float'
```

Would you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?
I need to find the x(angle) that makes this function minimum.

Comment: Please provide the full error stack trace; in particular, what line of your code it is referring to.

Comment: `scipy.optimize` doesn't work on complex-valued functions. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214326/4583620) for info on how to minimize a complex function.

Comment: Your function P1_adj has a CONSTANT amplitude (60450.64625041). Your graph appears to be plotting the real (or maybe, imaginary) part of a complex exponential only. So, what exactly are you trying to optimise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `optimize.minimize`  does not support complex numbers, funct `P1_adj` returns a `complex number`, which is causing the error.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy import optimize

def P1_adj(x):
    return np.abs(60450.64625041 * np.exp(1j * (57.29 * 1.75056445 + x)))

result = minimize(P1_adj, x0=0)
print(result)
```

- here `P1_adj` funct calculates the `absolute value` of the complex number instead of returning the complex number itself

Answer (score 0):

Notice your objective function

```
60450.64625041*np.exp(1j*(57.29*1.75056445+x))
```

`1j` here is a complex number, the solver doesn't know how to compare it with a typical float number. Convert it to a real number for it to work.

Comment: But my function is a complex numer.

Comment: what do you mean by minimizing a complex number?